# How to Resolve "Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll' "

Tags: uwp

I am working on Universal Windows Applications, in one of my project I want to connect the Azure SQL Database for that I had wrote below lines of code.

```
  try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = null;
            string query = null;
            //DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
            connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxx_db;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            connection.Open();
            // Converts image file into byte[]
            // byte[] imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(App.m_photoStorageFile.Path);
            //query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Delivery_Analytics.DeliveryPerson_Information] (Name,MobileNumber,CompanyName,DeliveryAddress,Image,Timestamp)" +
            //                "Values ('" + nameTxtBx.Text + "','" + mobileNumTxtBx.Text + "','" + comapanyNameTxtBx.Text + "','" + deliveryAddress + "','" + pictureTxtBx.Text + "','" + dateTime + "')";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

For the SqlConnection Class, I added the Reference as System.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0 after I added this reference to my project then now I have try to rebuild the project at that time I got the exception like below.

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\pradeep.nuget\packages\runtime.any.System.Diagnostics.Tools\4.0.1\lib\netcore50\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
C:\Users\pradeep.nuget\packages\System.Diagnostics.Tools\4.0.0\lib\netcore50\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll  SqlClientPOC**

Please tell me how to resolve this error as soon as possible.

Comment: have you looked in the directory C:\Users\pradeep.nuget\packages\runtime.any.System.Diagnostics.Tools\4.0.1\lib\netcore50\ to see if there are to identical dll files?

Comment: I already seen that location path but it doesn't contain two identical files it contains only one dll file.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you have a mismatch in which version of .net library you're referencing with different projects? At least, that's how it seems to me, or else you've got a reference hung up somewhere - have you tried deleting the nuget package for the version you don't want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't connect to Microsoft SQL Server directly from UWP Apps. The [System.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/) package you've referenced is a .Net Core library. We can use this library in .NET Core apps (either ASP.NET Core apps or Console apps), however, we can't use it in UWP apps.

The common way to access Microsoft SQL Server database form a UWP app is host a data service and the app query the data through REST API or WCF service. For example, you can check [How to access data from SQL Server database in Windows Store app](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/OneCode/How-to-access-data-from-SQL-Server-database-in-Windows-Store-app). This video shows how to create a WCF service to access data from SQL server database in Windows Store apps.

And since you are using Azure SQL Database, you can choose to use [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/) particularly [Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/appservice-mobileapps/) in your project. For more info, please see [Create a Windows app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/), [Work with the .NET backend server SDK for Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/) and [How to use the managed client for Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/).